# Как подключить JS с импортами, чтобы в body.onload определился объект?

Tags: javascript, html, импорт

Есть файл service.js, который начинается так:

```
import Access from "./controls/access.js"
import Menu from "./controls/menu.js"
import User from "./controls/user.js"
import Admin from "./controls/admin.js"

class Service
{ ...
```

Есть генерация странички на PHP:

```
$uri = $this->proto.$this->name."/public/";
$img = $uri."images";
$css = $uri."styles";
$js = $uri."scripts";
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
<head>
<title>My service</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="$img/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$css/style.css"/>
<script type="module" src="$js/service.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="new Service('$this->control','$this->action');"></body>
</html>
HTML;

header("content-type: text/html; charset: UTF-8");
exit($html);
```

При загрузке страницы в консоли браузера сообщение `Service is not defined`. Если не использовать `import` в js и подгружать все скрипты напрямую с `script type="application/javascript"` вместо `module`, то всё работает. Если же просто поменять тип на `application/javascript` и оставить импорты, то получается ошибка `import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`.

Как правильно подключить скрипт с импортами (или как-то изменить его), чтобы это заработало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как-то так:
Добавить

```
<script>var data={control: '$this->control', action: '$this->action'}</script>
```

А в конце service.js:

```
new Service(data.control,data.action);
```

Comment: Точно! Благодарю